# What is phonics?

Tags: teaching-methods, phonics

A [recent question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2517/800) asked about phonics. Even though the OP was mainly interested in English, the question implied that phonics is or can be used for other languages. However, I don't think phonics was properly explained there.

So:

- What is phonics?
- Where or in which languages is it used?
- Is it used only for learning to read and write one's native language or also on foreign language teaching?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Phonics** is a method of teaching English-speaking children to read and write **English** by connecting the phonemes (or sounds) of the spoken language with graphemes ("letters") or letter groups in the written language. Simply put, children learn

- that spoken words consist of a sequence of sounds (phonemes), e.g. cat: `/k/` + `/æ/` + `/t/`;
- that some sounds correspond to a letter group, e.g. `/ʃ/` for "sh", `/tʃ/` for "ch";
- to decode written words with the above knowledge.

This approach contrasts with approaches that teach to recognise whole words.

A [YouTube video by Dyslexia Australia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMvbUZTuL78) says that, "Studies have shown that if a child is not proficient with phonics or decoding by the end of year 2, chances are that they never will be."

The **British Department of Education** promotes this approach; see for example its [leaflet for parents (PDF)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/194057/phonics_check_leaflet_2013_.pdf). However, the article [Five things about phonics](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-18493436) (BBC News, June 2012) points out that:

> The government's phonics-only approach is controversial, with many teachers and educationalists advocating a more balanced approach in which other reading strategies are also used.
>   "Some children will need more phonics-teaching more than others," says Andrew Lambirth, professor of education at the University of Greenwich.

The article also mentions that the debate about how to teach children to read has been going on for decades adn that there was a more balanced approach in the 1970s and 1980s.

The English Teachers Association NSW in **Australia** published a [position statement](https://www.englishteacher.com.au/about-us/positions-on-english/on-reading-and-phonics) that points out, among other things, that phonics is just one part of a bigger set of reading strategies that learners are taught. The position statement contrasts the Australian approach with the strong emphasis on phonics in the **USA**:

> The USA through its national program, Reading first ,can be said to have effectively advocated phonics as the main method of reading instruction in US schools - with legislation reflecting a long history of phonics-based instruction in the US. In the 2003 international PISA test despite the "overwhelming scientific evidence" in favour of phonics-based instruction, 15 year-olds in the US scored significantly worse than Australia with its more inclusive reading instruction. Australia, in fact, was beaten by only one country - Finland.

The Australian position statement also quotes a paper by Stephen Krashen, which says, among other things, that the general public and the media in the USA support phonics instruction without being aware that there are several different phonics methods (intensive, systematic phonics, basic phonics, zero phonics).

Stephen Krashen briefly explains the differences between “intensive, systematic phonics”, “zero phonics” and “basic phonics” in a [letter to Education Week](http://www.edweek.org/ew/articles/2005/07/27/43letter-4.h24.html) (July 2005).
Get Reading Right has a webpage that explains the difference between [Analytic Phonics vs Synthetic Phonics](http://www.getreadingright.com.au/analytic-phonics-vs-synthetic-phonics/); in this comparison, synthetic phonics looks superior to the other approach.

The French Wikipedia article [**méthode syllabique**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_syllabique) mentions that the 18th-century Alsatian priest [Jean Georges Stuber](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Georges_Stuber) published a method similar to phonics as early as 1762 (*Alphabet méthodique pour faciliter l'art d'épeler et de lire en français*). The Wikipedia article does not mention the term "phonics" or how English-speaking children are taught to read. However, it mentions that, in 2005, the French minister of education Gilles de Robien had stated that the "méthode globale" (["whole language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_language)) should be abandoned once and for all.

I have not found evidence that phonics or the French "méthode syllabique/alphabétique" is used to teach children to read in a **foreign language**.

Here are a few links and references:

- [Phonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonics) on Wikipedia. Wikipedia defines phonics as a "method for teaching reading and writing of the **English** language by developing learners' phonemic awareness (...)" (emphasis added).
- National Literacy Trust: [Phonics - a definition](http://www.literacytrust.org.uk/resources/practical_resources_info/1030_phonics-a_definition) and [Phonics - methods of teaching](http://www.literacytrust.org.uk/resources/practical_resources_info/1035_phonics-methods_of_teaching).
- UK Department of Education: [Teaching phonics: information for schools](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/phonics) (March 2014).
- English Teachers Association NSW (Australia): [On Reading and Phonics](https://www.englishteacher.com.au/about-us/positions-on-english/on-reading-and-phonics) (position statement).
- Krashen, Stephen: "Defending Whole Language: The Limits of Phonics Instruction and the Efficacy of Whole Language Instruction", *Reading Improvement*, Vol. 39, Nr. 1 (Spring 2002). ([Abstract in ERIC](https://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ646958).)
- Oxford University Press ELT: [How to teach phonics to kindergarten children](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdI-_cO_zGQ) (6-minute video with teacher trainer Freia Layfield on YouTube).
- Torgesen, Joseph K.: "[Avoiding the Devastating Downward Spiral: The Evidence That Early Intervention Prevents Reading Failure](http://www.aft.org/periodical/american-educator/fall-2004/avoiding-devastating-downward-spiral)", *American Educator*, 2004. (Does not focus on phonics, but mentions research that says that "suggests that initial explicit instruction in phonics is useful for all children".)